# How to customize datetime format or to convert DateTime to String with required format

Tags: c#

I have a DateTime string in 24 HOURS format .. "2009-12-31T23:59:59"

I want it in this format .. "12/31/2009 23:59:59" that is: "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"
When I tried to covert it to string I am getting "12/31/2009 11:59:59 PM" .. though I can write a code for **string manipulation** .. it doesn't seem to be the efficient one .. Moreover the case become worst when I have dateTime value like "2009-1-1T1:19:15" .. here, as the **string length is varying**, I can't even trace the value of Hours and months using substring() and convert.ToInt() ..
 I am using visual studio 2005, It is throwing error saying "Cannot implicitly convert DateTime to String" when I write this statement:
..

```
result = Convert.ToString(dateValue);
```

I simplify my question:
Is there any method to convert "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss" format to "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" .. And it must work in visual studio 2005 ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use ParseExact to get it back to datetime:

```
string FormatDateTime(string dateString) {
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
    return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

That should give you the desired output you are looking for.  By using InvariantInfo, it will make sure you system settings don't replace the slashes with whatever you have currently defined in the system.  I think I saw in the comments that you had a "." being used as your date separator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.invariantinfo.aspx

Comment: no need to write ParseExact, just have to give the date format in the statement dateVaule.toString(date_format) .. like this way "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss" .. thats enough ......... Unholy is correct ..

Comment: What do you mean dateValue?  You mentioned nothing about that in your original post.  You really need to learn how to ask questions.

You probably don't realize, but if you let just the plain Parse try and figure out the date format it takes much longer than just providing it, to the parser intialially. That is why there are two different methods. Second Unholy was basing his entire thing off of his machine, which seems to be running a non-standard setup. But you shouldn't hack your own formating, a "/" is a date seperator, and you want it to always be a "/", use a culture that supports it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: When I tried you code I get the following:

DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") "12.09.2009 10:26:09"

Comment: No he had it right.  You default separator in you system has been defined as a "." instead of a "/".  See this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx

Comment: Yes, because of it we should use "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss".

Comment: Actually no, you should be using the InvariantInfo formatter, not hacking the string together with quoted date separators.

Comment: Read the document for more information on how the Date separators work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx

Comment: no need to write ParseExact, just have to give the date format in the statement dateVaule.toString(date_format) .. like this way "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy' 'HH':'mm':'ss" .. thats enough Unholy is correct ..

Answer (score 1):

```
string FormatDateString(string date_string)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(date_string, out date)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Unholy, do you mind explaining the significance of the apostrophe's in your format? I am not familiar with this. Thx :)

Comment: From msdn: "' - Represents a quoted string (apostrophe). Displays the literal value of any string between two apostrophe (') characters. "
When you use apostrophe you excplicitly define delimeter.

Answer (score -1):

It's something like this: `XmlConvert.ToDateTime(yourDate, "yyyy-MM-dd\Thh:mm:ss").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS")`

Check here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzk5c6y9.aspx