# How to convert datetime with offset to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: c#

How can date in this format : 2014-02-06T17:20:28.107Z
be converted to this exact format: 1/28/2014 18:07

I tried this:

```
public string FormatDate(string date)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return dt.ToString();
}
```

Which returned a Format Exception

Comment: this question/many variants of this question have already been asked and answered here on SO before. Please use this site as a resource, not ask a question before you've looked :(

Comment: Dont you think Ive looked?

Comment: I still can't figure out how the Date day, month and time changed ?

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590180/how-to-convert-a-datetime-string-to-a-current-culture-datetime-string or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316896/extracting-just-the-date-pattern-from-a-full-datetime-pattern?lq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871736/chow-to-customize-datetime-format-or-to-convert-datetime-to-string-with-requir?rq=1 . This list can quite easily continue. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to format the string when parsing, instead of when you print it out.

From the [`ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx), the format argument is what format your *input* is expected to be in.

You want to format the *output* instead.

Since the input looks like ISO8601, a simple parse will work.

I think what you're wanting to do is more likely:

```
public string FormatDate(string date)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);

    return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

I don't have Visual Studio so I don't have a way to test it right now, but that's definitely closer to what you're going for.

Comment: It definitely is safer, but it is not required in this specific example, is it?  Mainly because the input appears to be a standard ISO date/time format.

The fastest solution it seems is above, but if the input changed or anything like that, it could cause trouble.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that part of your answer, I wasn't aware it was a standard format :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern doesn't correspond at all with your input format. It looks like you didn't understand how it works

First apply a Parse with the appropriate pattern to get a DateTime, then after you convert it to string with the right pattern.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-02-06T17:20:28.107", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

return dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

In this case, "return" will produce a string which contains "02/06/2014 05:20".

The above patterns seems to be the one you need for explicit parse of your format, though there are maybe some predefined shortcuts for them, your date looks to be a standard ISO one, so maybe a simple Parse would work. My post is primarily done to explain where you look like to miss the point and how "parse" should be used.

Answer (score -2):

Was that string coming from DateTimeOffset data type? If so, you can just access the DateTime version via property date.DateTime ( in this case date will be DateTimeOffset type not string).

If it came straight as a string, then maybe try parse into DateTimeOffset first?

Comment: Im pulling the date from an APi as a string:  2014-02-06T17:20:28.107Z