# Conversion of Date format into YYYY-MM-DD Format

Tags: .net

I want to convert the date format in my page.

In asp.net, how to convert this Date format:

```
3/1/2015 12:00:00 AM (MM-DD-YYYY)
```

into:

```
2015-01-03 (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#:How to customize datetime format or to convert DateTime to String with required format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871736/chow-to-customize-datetime-format-or-to-convert-datetime-to-string-with-requir)

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? Which dates do you want to convert? Where do you want to display the dates?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String MyString = "3/1/2015 12:00:00 AM"; // get value from text field
DateTime MyDateTime = new DateTime();
MyDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",null);
String MyString_new = MyDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you search the internet like for example `String.Format()`?

```
String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now); //Output: 2015-05-22
```

Other formats you can find here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is`DateTime.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")`;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Why do you think that doesn't answar the question?You sure that's not going to work?